# permutation of a list of numbers done recursively in python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, permutation

So basically I'm trying to take a list of numbers and write a recursive function that outputs all possible outputs in a list of lists.

My code:

```
def permutations(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return lst
    l = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        m = lst[i]
        remlst = lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]
        for p in permutations(remlst):
            l.append([m] + p)
        return l
```

I'm getting a few errors about not being able to append int.

Simple output:

```
>>>permutations([1,2])
[[1,2],[2,1]]
```

Comment: give us a stacktrace :)

Answer (score 3):

There is an implementation for that in itertools:

```
import itertools
for p in itertools.permutations(list):
   # do stuff
```

Also, to fix your own function, notice that in your "base case" `len(lst) <= 1` your returning a list, instead of a list-of-lists. Also, the second return statement should be moved out of the loop;

```
def permutations(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return [lst]
    l = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        m = lst[i]
        remlst = lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]
        for p in permutations(remlst):
            l.append([m] + p)
    return l
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you iterate through result of `permutations`

```
for p in permutations(remlst):
```

your base case needs to return a list of lists like your recursive case does, otherwise you get the error `TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list`

You also need to return after the outer for loop.

```
def permutations(lst):
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return [lst] # [[X]]
    l = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        m = lst[i]
        remlst = lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]
        for p in permutations(remlst):
            l.append([m] + p)
    return l # return at end of outer for loop
```